# PHP Syntax Error in OpenCart

Tags: php, syntax-error, opencart

I tried to access customer section of opencart in the admin panel and got this message

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '&&' (T_BOOLEAN_AND), expecting ')' in /var/www/vhosts/cloud9herbals.com/cloud9hemp/dev/admin/controller/customer/customer.php on line 1105

This is the code on line 1105

```
} elseif (($custom_field['type'] == 'text' && !empty($custom_field['validation'] && $custom_field['location'] == 'address')) && !filter_var($value['custom_field'][$custom_field['custom_field_id']], FILTER_VALIDATE_REGEXP, array('options' => array('regexp' => $custom_field['validation'])))) {
```

If that isn't enough here is the entire statemnt

```
foreach ($custom_fields as $custom_field) {
                if (($custom_field['location'] == 'address') && $custom_field['required'] && empty($value['custom_field'][$custom_field['custom_field_id']])) {
                    $this->error['address'][$key]['custom_field'][$custom_field['custom_field_id']] = sprintf($this->language->get('error_custom_field'), $custom_field['name']);
                } elseif (($custom_field['type'] == 'text' && !empty($custom_field['validation'] && $custom_field['location'] == 'address')) && !filter_var($value['custom_field'][$custom_field['custom_field_id']], FILTER_VALIDATE_REGEXP, array('options' => array('regexp' => $custom_field['validation'])))) {
                    $this->error['address'][$key]['custom_field'][$custom_field['custom_field_id']] = sprintf($this->language->get('error_custom_field_validate'), $custom_field['name']);
                }
            }
```

I know very little about php but would really like to fix this issue

Comment: You never closed the `empty`. `!empty($custom_field['validation']`.

Comment: Also this is an extremely hard piece of code to read. You practice better formatting, break this stuff up a little.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this

```
empty($custom_field['validation'] && $custom_field['location'] == 'address'))
```

needs to be

```
empty($custom_field['validation']) && $custom_field['location'] == 'address')
```